# Can I use "sticky-top" in a responsive navbar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem by adding the Sticky-top function to a navbar in a Django proyect. The navbar is responsive and can be desplegated by clicking a button, but I want it to be always present in the top when te user scroll down.

I'm using the next code:

```
<div id="navBar"><!--Barra de navegación-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top" id="mainNavbar" >
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" ></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" id="collapse-button"data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span>Menu</span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-link" >
              <a href="home">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="contact">Contacto</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#containers) do not explicitly declare this but if you look at all the samples they only ever nest the `nav.navbar` inside a `div.container`. I was only able to get your code to work **properly** after removing the `#navBar` wrapper.

**Not recommended:**
It will also work if you apply the class `sticky-top` directly to the `#navBar` wrapper instead of the `nav.navbar` but that seems to go against the intended usage and therefore it may not work in every browser.